# get string keys using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

```
(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR)\s(.*?):
```

for example

```
a:b:c AND d:e OR f:g:h:i AND NOT j:k
```

I want the regex to match [a,d,f,j]
But now it only matches [d,f,j]

in the following example it's matching only keys coming after AND NOT | OR | AND, but I want it to match the first key also...
https://regex101.com/r/iUZLOq/2

Comment: what are you trying to match from what?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for that:

```
(^|AND\sNOT\s|AND\s|OR\s)(.*?):
```

https://regex101.com/r/omwkQ3/1

^: is the beginning of the Line

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
([a-z])(:[a-z])*
```

You will match a little more you need. However, when you display only first matched bracket. It can (probably) be done by changing default (display all marches), to:

```
$1
```

You end up with:

```
[a, d, f, j]
```